# Radio buttons with custom icons

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have `ionic 3` radio buttons.Now I need to replace it with the custom icons.How can I do that?

Finally, it should be like this:

[image]

Custom icons are `<i class="cicon-crib"></i>` and `<i class="cicon-nursing"></i>`.

Normal radio buttons:

```
<ion-grid radio-group formControlName="location">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-12>
         <ion-item>
          <ion-label>On own in bed</ion-label>
          <ion-radio value="crib"></ion-radio>
         </ion-item>
     </ion-col>
   </ion-row>
      <ion-row>
       <ion-col col-12>
         <ion-item>
           <ion-label>Nursing</ion-label>
           <ion-radio value="nursing"></ion-radio>
           </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
     </ion-row>
 </ion-grid>
```

Comment: Could this help you? https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/extending-radio-buttons-to-have-icons-when-unchecked/31959

Comment: It is for Ionic 1 and no answer too. @SrAxi

Comment: that link @SrAxi provided is not a question.(it is in ionic1 , I agree).it is a show case of    work. refer this link http://play.ionic.io/app/824b61834b3e

Comment: @varunaaruru Yes, I just sent the 'parent' link so he could also read the description and then click to the link you posted to see the code. Thanks! ;)

Comment: How can I use `Ionic 1` solution with `Ionic 3`? Now It's completely different architecture no? Can't we find the `Ionic 2` solution for this? @varunaaruru

Comment: I am on it sir..I will share if I get succeeded :-)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/La8wQ/10/ this one is pure html and css

Comment: able to solve this sir? @Sampath

Comment: Please put your comment as a solution.Thanks @varunaaruru